# How to Trim Headings in a table with VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, trim, tableheader

I'm trying to trim the headings of a table with VBA code because some of them have spaces in front that varies every month, which makes it difficult for coding.

When I break down the code and run it step by step it works fine but when I run the whole macro it removes some of my headings and replace them with info from a different sheet row or just "column 1", "column 2", etc.

I believe I'm missing some code reference when it calls the `(" & .Address & ")` selection?

It's replacing the headings from a sheet where the cell is active. (If it was the last cell to click on before running the macro).

I've tried just using the **Trim** function, but because it's an array for the range, it doesn't work, and someone suggested to use the "**evaluate**" function.

I've tried using the trim function as a WorksheetFunction as well but it gave me an error "Run-time error 13" Type-mismatch". Which was on the following code:

```
    With wsDispoData.ListObjects("Table_DispoData").HeaderRowRange.EntireRow
        .Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Value)
    End With
```

This is the current code I'm using that replaces wrongly.

```
Trim headings
    With wsDispoData.ListObjects("Table_DispoData").HeaderRowRange.EntireRow
        .Value = Evaluate("IF(ISTEXT(" & .Address & "),TRIM(" & .Address & "),REPT(" & .Address & ",1))")
    End With
```

Expected results should be for example:

Current headings: "   SOH" and "      Compo"

Trimmed: "SOH" and "Compo"

Comment: Not too sure but try: `.Address(ColumnAbsolute:=False)`

Comment: @Dean unfortunately, I still get the same wrong replacement in the headings

Comment: Your code works for me... Are you sure those are actually spaces and not non printable characters?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. The code worked perfectly. • Note that *"didn't work"* is not an error description. Which errors do you get? What happens? Is there a `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout they are definitely spaces. As mentioned above the code works on it's own or if I run the macro in breaks, but not if I run the whole long macro. I've edit my question with an update. It seems It's replacing the headings with whichever cell and sheet is selected.

Comment: In that case I need to see the complete macro. You maybe resetting the range somewhere in the code

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The code I used for that doesn't work because it's an array is the following:     With wsDispoData.ListObjects("Table_DispoData").HeaderRowRange.EntireRow
        .Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Value)
    End With. It gives an error "Run-time error 13: type mismatch"

Comment: @SiddharthRout It is a very very long macro, and I use this trim code on 4 different tables. I tried running the code and stop it just before it starts on the second table, but it changes the headings even before it gets to that point. Should I post a section of the code?

Comment: `.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Value)` is wrong as it applies to `.EntireRow` so it refers to all cell in the entire row (16K columns) while `Trim` inputs a single value. What happens if you omit `.EntireRow`?

Comment: @AcsErno I'm using the `Evaluate` function instead of the `WorksheetFunction.Trim` because the range is an array which the `Trim` function doesn't work with since it's not a single cell or value. I've tried to remove the `.EntireRow` just to test and I get  the error  "Run-time error 13" Type-mismatch" as mentioned in the post

Comment: @Simone Fick Yes, that was a quick and wrong advise. To take it seriously: Type mismatch by omitting entirerow is correct as headerrowrange returns a range, not a string. So you might try `For Each c in wsDispoData.ListObjects("Table_DispoData").HeaderRowRange: c.Value = Trim(c.Value) : Next`

Comment: @AcsErno Thought I would get away from doing a loop, but it works perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just enumerate through the header row and check each value

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In wsDispoData.ListObjects("Table_DispoData").HeaderRowRange
    Cell.value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cell.value)
Next Cell
```

Comment: thank you it is the same answer as 'AcsErno'. Works perfectly.